# Model Driven Form Nested FormArray Control in a FormGroup control

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I have a form group like so:

```
 this.form = fb.group({
  'teacher': [''],
  'schools': fb.array([
      fb.group({
        'school_name': [''],
        'school_description': [''],
        'events': fb.array([
          fb.group({
            'event_name': ['']
          })
        ])
      })
  ])
});
const control = (<FormArray>this.form.controls['schools']).controls[0]['events'];
```

How do I get the nested array control 'events'?

```
const control = (<FormArray>this.form.controls['schools']).controls[0]['events'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend having a look at the Angular 2 examples for [nested form array](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2a3ca7bfcfc4c861687eec252cc01ffc55796134/modules/%40angular/examples/forms/ts/nestedFormArray/nested_form_array_example.ts) and [nested form group](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2a3ca7bfcfc4c861687eec252cc01ffc55796134/modules/%40angular/examples/forms/ts/nestedFormGroup/nested_form_group_example.ts) for a look at how to build complex forms. With FormGroup, you can use `.get(name: string)` to retrieve a control. This example gets the `schools` FormArray control:

```
this.form.get('schools')
```

For FormArray, you can retrieve a control from the array using `.at(index: number)`. This example gets the first FormGroup control in the array:

```
this.schools.at(0)
```

To put it all together, there are nicer (read: more reusable, more readable) ways to express this but this chain will get you the first event from your first school:

```
this.form.get('schools').at(0).get('events')
```

Here's a working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FhZUrv?p=preview) example.

Comment: Hey Thanks, Your advice really helped. I actually got it to work using: 
`const control = (<FormArray>this._form.controls['schools']).at(i).get('events') as FormArray;`
Here is a working example: [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/rjzrwN/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code:

```
      let listForm: any;
      var subFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
        subFormGroup.addControl("Your Controll Name", new FormControl('',res["Required"] ? Validators.required : null))

      listForm = this.builder.array([
        subFormGroup
      ]);
      this.form.addControl("Your new ArrayControll Name", listForm);
```

When you have an Array of Object,you can use that:

```
 let listForm: any;
 var controlItems =[Your Object Array];
 var subFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
 Object.keys(controlItems).forEach(function(key){
    subFormGroup.addControl(controlItems[key], new FormControl('',res["Required"] ? Validators.required : null))
  })
 listForm = this.builder.array([
     subFormGroup
 ]);
 this.form.addControl("Your new ArrayControll Name", listForm);
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, I actually got it to work using: 
`const control = (<FormArray>this._form.controls['schools']).at(i).get('events') as FormArray;`
Here is a working example: [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/rjzrwN/)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change a value for a nested FormArray, for me this works:

`(<FormArray>this.formModel.controls['schools']).at(el).patchValue({school_name:'your new value'});`

**el** is the index element for which one you want to apply the patch value.

Comment: (<FormArray>this.formModel.controls['schools']).at(0).get('events);